# Within MDT can we specify `UserID` in the `Bootstrap.ini` based on MAC address?

Tags: mdt

We have an MDT server provisioned in our environment that used for two processes.

1. The deployment of PCs. i.e. Help Desk personnel provision new machines using the images in MDT/WDS.
2. A nightly hands-off process related to MDT.

Within the `Bootstrap.ini` file we have the following settings:

```
[Default]
SkipBDDWelcome=YES
DeployRoot=\\192.168.1.2\DeploymentShare$
UserID=example
UserPassword=hello
UserDomain=me.local
```

This works great. Meaning, when someone loads LiteTouch they are not asked to authentication. They are instead just taken right into selecting the Task Sequence.

That said, what I would really like to do is set the `UserID`, `UserPassword` and `UserDomain` based on the MAC address. Basically, something like what's below:

```
[Default]
SkipBDDWelcome=YES
DeployRoot=\\192.168.1.2\DeploymentShare$

[7A-81-CC-E9-A4-70]
UserID=example
UserPassword=hello
UserDomain=me.local
```

The idea being that, everyone should need to authenticate *except* for one specific MAC address. If the computer being imaged has the MAC address specified above, then use the `UserID` (etc) values specified above.

I tried this a couple of times, and LiteTouch appears to ignore the credentials unless they are under `[Default]`. I can't find any documentation to know whether that's buy design, or if there is something I'm doing wrong.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: First question, what is the point of doing that? So I can help you to get to the end goal.

Comment: @ZoranJankov, we're using MDT for two processes. One is a zero-touch process that runs each night. That process is a tied to a specific task sequence that automatically launches when for a specific MAC address, and requires that MDT launch, select and run the task sequence without LiteTouch prompting for a username/password. As for the other usecase, it is a help desk technician provisioning PCs.

Comment: I would like a) the zero-touch process to continue to function as it currently does, i.e. auto-authenticate using the credentials based on the computers MAC address. And, b) for LiteTouch to prompt any other computer/user to authenticate when trying to use  MDT/LiteTouch.

Comment: Checking in to see if anyone else had any comments.

Comment: I don't think that is possible with MDT. You would need MS Endpoint Configuration Manager SCCM for that.

Comment: Hmm... I'm going to admit that I wish I better understood your answer, @ZoranJankov. I don't know of a feature in Endpoint Configuration Manager that would allow this functionality over MDT on its own.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to revive an old thread.

Have you tried to change Priority under Settings to include "Selection by MACAddress"?

```
[Settings]
Priority = MACAddress, Default

[Default]
SkipBDDWelcome=YES
DeployRoot=\\192.168.1.2\DeploymentShare$

[7A:81:CC:E9:A4:70]
UserID=example
UserPassword=hello
UserDomain=me.local
```

MAC addresses should be separated by colons ':'

Comment: I finally got around to testing this, and it worked flawlessly. Thank you for the suggestion.